# react-social-media-embed: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I was trying to use "react-social-media-embed" in my Next TS project. I did the following:

`npm i react-social-media-embed`

my `page.tsx` looks like this:

```
import { InstagramEmbed } from 'react-social-media-embed';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main className={`${styles.main} max-w-screen-xl font-serif font-thin`}>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <InstagramEmbed url="https://www.instagram.com/p/CUbHfhpswxt/" width={328} />
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

All very simple, but when compiling I got this error in browser:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client Components. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Component
node_modules/react-youtube/dist/YouTube.js (144:50)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-youtube/dist/YouTube.js
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/app/page.js (2491:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
require
node_modules/react-social-media-embed/dist/components/embeds/YouTubeEmbed.js (43:40)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-social-media-embed/dist/components/embeds/YouTubeEmbed.js
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/app/page.js (2382:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
require
node_modules/react-social-media-embed/dist/index.js (23:13)
(sc_server)/./node_modules/react-social-media-embed/dist/index.js
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/app/page.js (2459:1)
__webpack_require__
file:///Users/xiaohandu/sanctum-wellbeing/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
eval
webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./src/app/page.tsx (9:82)
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error already states the issue

> This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a
> Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client
> Components. Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component

change current component to client component by adding

```
"use client"
```

on top the file

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly I could not find much useful information online regarding this issue